# Vertica aggregate function calls may not be nested

Tags: sql, vertica

Below are my query,when I run it, I'm getting the error

> aggregate function calls may not be nested

Any ideas why?

```
select 
  country
, client
, COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn) as 'Total_number_of_MSISDN'
, count(*) as 'Total_number_of_MSISDN'
, count(case when COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn) then 1 end ) 
from my_table
where CAST(time_updated as DATE) = CURRENT_DATE-1
and action_status='COMPLETED' and "ACTION" ='CHARGE'
GROUP BY 
  country
, client
ORDER BY 
  country
, client
```

[image: My_table and expected output]

Comment: The reason is this: `count(case when COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn) then 1 end)`  but the expression `when COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn)` does not make any sense. What is it you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i need to get total of distinct msisdn ,for example for country CH,there is total 2 msisdn repeated

Comment: KY LIM -  for CH, you already have the value 2 in `Number_of_Distinct_MSISDN`. Just as a_horse_with_no_name, I don't understand what you want with the 3rd measure. I notice that INDIA and A get 4 in the first measure and 0 in the third. Do you happen to mean the number of rows that are duplicates of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below is the closest I can get to what you're expecting; the result for 'SG' and 'A', however, returns 1 and not 2, in my case.

Now, I'm just guessing you'd like to count that for 2 because you have two different groups on your input list - the way it's (not) sorted. If it is that information that you want to take into account, you would need to add a sequence column, and then use OLAP functions like LAG() or LEAD(), I think.

And it's obvious that your WHERE condition is complete nonsense with the example table you supplied.

This is the closest I could get to with just your input data:

```
WITH 
-- input
my_table(country,client,msisdn) AS (
          SELECT 'MY','A',111
UNION ALL SELECT 'INDIA','A',112
UNION ALL SELECT 'SG','A',113
UNION ALL SELECT 'SG','A',113
UNION ALL SELECT 'SG','A',113
UNION ALL SELECT 'INDIA','A',126
UNION ALL SELECT 'SG','A',113
UNION ALL SELECT 'INDIA','A',116
UNION ALL SELECT 'INDIA','A',120
UNION ALL SELECT 'CH','D',115
UNION ALL SELECT 'CH','D',115
UNION ALL SELECT 'MY','B',117
UNION ALL SELECT 'INDIA','B',118
UNION ALL SELECT 'SG','C',119
UNION ALL SELECT 'CH','D',199
UNION ALL SELECT 'CH','D',199
)
,
-- rows occurring more than once
dups AS (
SELECT
  country
, client
, msisdn
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
  country
, client
, msisdn
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
  m.country
, m.client
, COUNT(DISTINCT m.msisdn) AS 'Number_of_distinct_MSISDN'
, COUNT(*) AS 'Total_number_of_MSISDN'
, COUNT(DISTINCT d.msisdn) AS total_distinct_MSISDN
FROM my_table m
LEFT JOIN dups d USING(country,client,msisdn)
-- where CAST(time_updated as DATE) = CURRENT_DATE-1
-- and action_status='COMPLETED' and "ACTION" ='CHARGE'
GROUP BY 
  m.country
, m.client
ORDER BY
  m.country
, m.client
;

country|client|Number_of_distinct_MSISDN|Total_number_of_MSISDN|total_distinct_MSN
CH     |D     |                        2|                     4|                    2
INDIA  |A     |                        4|                     4|                    0
INDIA  |B     |                        1|                     1|                    0
MY     |A     |                        1|                     1|                    0
MY     |B     |                        1|                     1|                    0
SG     |A     |                        1|                     4|                    1
SG     |C     |                        1|                     1|                    0
```

Good luck - 
Marco